# Binaries built on Windows 7 fails on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-7-x64, windows-server-2012

An application built on nightly build machine does not work on Windows Server 2012 but works fine on other desktops.

An exception of the kind
"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." is thrown.

When I debug using remote debugging across the WindowsServer2012 machine and build machine, I see that this exception is thrown at a place where kernel32 call [HeapSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is made in the code.  Here is how `HeapSize` is imported and called :

```
[DllImport("kernel32")] 
static extern int HeapSize(int hHeap, int flags, void* block); 
// Returns the size of a memory block. 

public static int SizeOf(void* block) 
{ 
    int result = HeapSize(ph, 0, block); 
    if (result == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException(); 
    return result; 
}
```

This is called as part of an unsafe class's constructor:

```
    public UnManagedBuffer(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        PtrStart = (byte*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(sb.ToString());
        Size = UnManagedMemory.SizeOf(PtrStart);
        PtrWriteNextValue = PtrStart + Size - 1;
        PtrReturnNextValue = PtrStart;
    }
```

Any clues on what could be missing and how to fix this?

This is what I see in Windbg:

[image: This is what I see in Windbg]

EventLog shows:

```
    Log Name:      Application
    Source:        .NET Runtime
    Level:         Error
    Keywords:      Classic
    Description:
Application: TestEngine.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at Core.Utils.UnManagedMemory.HeapSize(Int32, Int32, Void*)
   at Core.Utils.UnManagedMemory.SizeOf(Void*)
   at Core.Utils.UnManagedBuffer..ctor</Event>

Faulting application name: TestEngine.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x56b532bb
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18185, time stamp: 0x5683f0c5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000057306
Faulting process id: 0x2eb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d164e45b12d7dd
Faulting application path: C:\NGDLM\Lib\TestEngine.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: bea6eb89-d0d7-11e5-80eb-0050568cd888
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Are you using PInvoke to call HeapSize? Can you show the method declaration? (Also, are all the machines the same architecture, ie x86 vs x64?)

Comment: Take a crash dump, poke at it with [windbg+SOS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2011/04/11/intro-to-windbg-for-net-developers/)

Comment: Yes configuration is the same - both machines are x64 and code is built in x64 config.
The code is:

[DllImport("kernel32")]
static extern int HeapSize(int hHeap, int flags, void* block);
 // Returns the size of a memory block.
 public static int SizeOf(void* block)
{
int result = HeapSize(ph, 0, block);
if (result == -1) throw new InvalidOperationException();
return result;
}

Comment: Are you using unsafe code?

Comment: @user5900294 It's always good if you can [edit] your question to add code when requested - this keeps the question coherent and easier to read.  I've made the edit for you here this time.

Comment: Thanks Jessen! @stuartd it is ca constructor call of an unsafe class - I have added the code above

Comment: Have you tried using [GlobalSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366593(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of HeapSize? Though the memory ultimately comes from the same heap space, I am under the impression that memory allocated by Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi is allocated with the Global* functions, so it would make sense to also use the function from that family to query the size.

Comment: It could be triggering Data Execution Prevention on the server. Is there anything in the server event logs?

Comment: @RobertKenny, I have appended the event log to the question now.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, documentation says: Note  The global functions have greater overhead and provide fewer features than other memory management functions. New applications should use the heap functions unless documentation states that a global function should be used.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've written should not have ever worked.

`HeapSize` returns the size of a heap, eg, something allocated by calling [HeapAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The pointer provided to `HeapSize` must be the pointer returned by calling `HeapAlloc`:

> lpMem [in]
>
> > A pointer to the memory block whose size the function will obtain. This is a pointer returned by the HeapAlloc or HeapReAlloc function.

You're calling `HeapSize`, but providing a pointer that could be anywhere within that heap; or not in that heap at all:

```
    PtrStart = (byte*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(sb.ToString());
    Size = UnManagedMemory.SizeOf(PtrStart);
    PtrWriteNextValue = PtrStart + Size - 1;
    PtrReturnNextValue = PtrStart;
```

Not only will  `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi()` return a pointer somewhere in the heap, and not a pointer to the heap itself, you don't even know *which* heap the pointer was allocated from, because the process could have multiple heaps allocated.

All of that doesn't matter, because it appears you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the purpose of this function - you appear to be using it to retrieve the size of an allocation made inside a heap. The memory returned by `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi()` is not allocated by calling `HeapAlloc()` (because it's not a heap!), it's allocated by calling [AllocHGlobal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal(v=vs.100).aspx). The memory allocated by it has to be freed by calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal()`:

From [`Marshal.StringToHGlobal()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs,6a0a9abff99fc610)'s documentation:

> Because this method allocates the unmanaged memory required for a string, always free the memory by calling FreeHGlobal.

This `Marshal` method has nothing to do with `HeapAlloc`, `HeapSize` or related functions.

If you did actually want to find out the size of the memory allocation of the pointer returned by `Marshal.StringToHGlobal()`, you could dig through the [source of the the Marshal class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and find out that it uses the win32 function [`LocalAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It so happens that `LocalAlloc` has a sister function [`LocalSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which indeed can be used to find the size of an allocation.

However, there is no guarantee that doing so will work in the future, because the .Net framework provides no guarantee that it'll continue to use `LocalAlloc`. If they changed the internals `LocalSize` might stop working.

...

All of that said:

## I don't think any of this is what you meant to do in the first place

Looking at your code again:

```
    PtrStart = (byte*)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(sb.ToString());
    Size = UnManagedMemory.SizeOf(PtrStart);
    PtrWriteNextValue = PtrStart + Size - 1;
    PtrReturnNextValue = PtrStart;
```

You're trying to find the length of the ansi string returned to you.

All of this business of `HeapSize` or `LocalSize` is completely irrelevant.

If you just want to find the length of an 'ansi' string, you just need to implement a stupid simple string length, or use any of the implementations already there for you.

The following program uses `Marshal.StringToHGlobal()`, and prints:

> String: 'Hello'; Length: 5

```
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        IntPtr strPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        string str = "Hello";
        try
        {
            strPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi( str );

            Console.Out.WriteLine( "String: '{0}'; Length: {1}", str, AnsiStrLen( strPtr ) );
        }
        finally
        {
            if( strPtr != IntPtr.Zero )
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal( strPtr );
            }
        }
    }

    public static int AnsiStrLen( IntPtr strPtr )
    {
        int size = 0;

        while( Marshal.ReadByte( strPtr ) != 0 )
        {
            size++;
            strPtr = IntPtr.Add( strPtr, 1 );
        }

        return size;
    }
```